# Is it possible to have Vertical Row Groupings with Ag Grid?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ag-grid

I'm creating an application that will have an editable table. I've used Ag-Grid before and have found it to be very useful. I've been searching and reading the documentation for a couple of hours now and haven't found any such example of the below image. Is it possible to do something like this in Ag-Grid?

The only thing I've found for grouping hides rows in a tree-like structure. If it's not possible, is there another angular table library that might work?

[image]

Comment: considered using CSS grid ? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try? - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/
Or another one thing:
groupRowRenderer, groupRowRendererParams -If grouping, allows custom rendering of the group cell. Use this if you are not happy with the default presentation of the group.

Comment: This was perfect. Annoyed I couldn't find this in the documentation but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. With some cell styling, I was able to rotate the text after setting the span.

Comment: That's awesome. I glad that help you.